# How to get mobile country code on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get phone country code using flutter?

**(+972, +92)**

I tried with `localOf`. But I can't get country code.

```
Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
```

output is `US, or en-US`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Localizations` doesn't have phone codes, you could use a library or define a map with country codes and phone codes, and then access to it by country.

```
static const countryPhoneCodes = {"US": "+1", "AR": "+54"};

print('${countryPhoneCodes['US']}'); // output: +1
```

Then in your case you would be able to do something like this:

```
print('${countryPhoneCodes[myLocale.countryCode]}');
```

---

From this library [country_pickers](https://pub.dev/packages/country_pickers) you could get the codes here: [countries.dart](https://github.com/figengungor/country_pickers/blob/master/lib/countries.dart) or from [country_code_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker) here [country_codes.dart](https://github.com/imtoori/CountryCodePicker/blob/master/lib/country_codes.dart), or search the codes somewhere else.

Comment: Is there no way to get country code based on location without hardcoding?

Comment: Yes, in your case you could use myLocale.countryCode

Comment: Thank you for the map of the country code. It's has helped me.